# File name not shown in Eye of Gnome (eog)

Tags: eog

My Eye of Gnome doesn't show me the image file name in the top bar.

I wonder how could I retrieve this very useful information?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity.

### Update:

Here is an image in EoG:

[image: bug eog]

```
$ uname -a
Linux computername 4.6.1-040601-generic #201606100454 SMP Fri Jun 10 08:56:35 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ eog --version
Visionneur d'images de GNOME 3.18.2
```

I remember in older Ubuntu versions that the file name was displayed in the top bar of the EoG window.

Comment: My installation of EoG displays the name of the current file in the application title bar on Trusty with Gnome Shell. Which window compositor or desktop environment are you using? Could you please [edit] your question to clarify that and maybe add a screenshot of your EoG to illustrate the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Edited! Don't hesistate to ask for more infos if needed.

Comment: What happens when you press the  `F11` key?

Comment: It goes full screen. And when I press a 2nd time, it comes back to normal. And file name is still not displayed.

Comment: From the screenshot, I notice the zoom selection control in the top bar, and number of pixels, file size, and zoom percentage in the bottom bar are not displayed either.

Comment: I'm testing now in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS live. When a small window, the file name is displayed. When the window is made to fill the available screen with the square control button at the top left corner (of the window), the file name is displayed, *except* when I move the cursor to the top bar, then I get something like you show: Image, Edit, View, Go, Help. The file name is displayed again, when I move the cursor down to the image itself. Is this something you recognize?

Comment: I voted to reopen the question because from the screenshot,it is completely clear that parts of the window are missing. Or have they been added since version 3.18?

Comment: No I don't recognize. The image is not displayed in full screen and when I "mouse over" it, or over the bar and then back elsewhere, nothing changes.     The only change is that when mouse is over, there is 4 small arrows: one left to go to previous image, one right to go to the next and two curved arrows down to rotate it. I can also zoom in/out with scroll on the touchpad and then a zoom bar appears near the "+" on top. That's all.

Comment: I also tried to `uninstall --purge eog` and then reinstall it, but there is no improvements.

Comment: So your EoG is *not* behaving like in the live session. You have a different kernel series , 4.6... according to `uname`. How did you install your system, (from which iso file)? How have you updated & upgraded it? What applications and drivers have you installed. - Has EoG always behaved like this in this particular system or has the file name disappeared after some update& upgrade? Have you tweaked the desktop environment?

Comment: Nothing was tweak except I had upgrade the kernel, a long time ago. It always had this behavior. I just checked on an other computer with the same Ubuntu fresh Ubuntu version and there it's working... Could the kernel be the culprit in some way?

Comment: I don't think the kernel is the culprit, but I am not sure. I think some other software (for example a library) may be causing this issue. I checked in my 'workhorse', Lubuntu 16.04 LTS with some extras. This system is up to date, and I have EoG there, the same version as you have,3.18.2. Anyway, it behaves like it should.

Comment: ... a library or maybe the *locale*, you have French. Have you tried with another locale (for example standard US English)? - I'm guessing here.

Comment: Actually, the other Ubuntu version I tested was in english, indeed.

Comment: Let us continue in a chat room, that is offered automatically :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61517/discussion-between-sudodus-and-s-k).